# Theora_image_transport Packet not paired through ROS1_Bridge

Tags: ros, ros2, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Laptop on Ubuntu 20.4
Noetic and Foxy installed.

I'm running a usb_cam node on my laptop on Noetic.

When I run ROS1_bridge, the image_raw and image_raw/compressed are forwarded to ROS2 but not the image_raw_theora topic.

I checked if the pair was available with ROS1_bridge and it's not the case.
As far as I understood, when compiling ros1_bridge is looking for every *_msgs package. The issue here is that theora_image_transport is not finishing by msgs

I tried to compile on my own the package image transport but It didn't changed anything.

Do you have any clues on the issue ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402068/theora_image_transport-packet-not-paired-through-ros1_bridge/) by [Mechaick](https://answers.ros.org/users/103895/mechaick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2022-06-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the issue by forking the ros1_bridge.
The issue was that ros1_bridge only forward messages that are from a package finishing by "_msgs"

If needed here is my fork, you can also easily implement any package not finishing by _msgs just by modifying the lines 481 and 482 of __init.py
https://github.com/Mechaick/ros1_bridge

---

Originally posted by [Mechaick](https://answers.ros.org/users/103895/mechaick/) with karma: 31 on 2022-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1